# Python Pillow lowering image quality doesnt change file size

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to lower the file size of an image using pillow (pil) however lowering the image quality doesn't lower the size of the saves image.
The saved images 'image2' and 'image3' are the same size.

```
import PIL from Image

im = Image.open('image.png')

im.save('image2.png', quality=100)
im.save('image3.png', quality=10)
```

Answer (score 2):

The PNG format only supports lossless compression, for which the compression ratio is usually limited and not freely adjustable.

If I am right, there is a variable parameter that tells the compressor to spend more or less time finding a better compression scheme. But without a guarantee to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use image compression to reduce sizes - pngquant or similar
https://pngquant.org/